# Full text search does not work in mysql 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

The below code worked in MySQL 5.0.24a but is no longer working in MySQL 5.5.

`$q` is UTF8 character.

```
SELECT *,MATCH(p.name,p.keywords) AGAINST('$q') AS pscore 
FROM products as p 
WHERE MATCH(p.name,p.keywords) AGAINST('$q') ORDER BY pscore DESC
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get no results? An error message?

Comment: db schema? are the tables indexed properly?

Comment: i assume $q is a php variable :-)

Comment: What's the character set of the `name` and `keywords` columns? Also, you appear to be using FULLTEXT search in "natural language mode", which will by default ignore any words shorter than four characters. So in theory, your query should not even have worked in the first place if $q is a single character. (Edit: Unless I'm misreading the docs and the minimum length only applies to the indexed columns, not the query.)

Comment: `$q` is a [SQL injection point](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.5 (or 5.5.5 precisely), InnoDB is the default storage engine, any table that have no specified storage engine, such as Engine=MyISAM will be created as InnoDB automagically, creating a lot of troubles. :(

I suspect this is your problem, as many production site have encountered that one!